# tf.keras.Sequential model creation does not return while using Tensorflow Distributive Strategy on 2 PCs

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

1I am using TensorFlow 2.10 on one Windows 11 PC and TensorFlow 2.14 on another Windows 11 PC as a chief and a worker node (chief and worker interchanged and result is the same). The strategy.scope() wraps the model creation and compile. I can see that the gRPC communication is healthy, coordination manager is happy and cluster is established. The TensorFlow multi-worker code runs fine until it calls tf.keras.Sequential() model creation where the **code never returns**

The code below is what I am using:

```
import os
import json
import numpy as np
import time

os.environ['TF_CONFIG'] = json.dumps({
'cluster': {
    'chief': ['x.x.x.x:5001'],
    'worker': ['x.x.x.x:5000'],
},
'task': {
    'type': 'chief',
    'index': 0
}
})

os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'

import tensorflow as tf

strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy(
       communication=tf.distribute.experimental.CollectiveCommunication.AUTO)

BUFFER_SIZE = 10000
BATCH_SIZE = 64


def mnist_dataset(batch_size):
    (x_train, y_train), _ = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
    # The `x` arrays are in uint8 and have values in the [0, 255] range.
    # You need to convert them to float32 with values in the [0, 1] range.
    print(f"Shape of the NumPy array: {len(x_train)}")
    x_train = x_train / np.float32(255)
    y_train = y_train.astype(np.int64)
    
    train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
        (x_train, y_train)).shuffle(60000).repeat().batch(batch_size)
    return train_dataset

def build_and_compile_cnn_model():
    # Create a simple neural network model
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'), 
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
    ])
    model.compile(
        loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
        optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.001),
        metrics=['accuracy'])

 return model


GLOBAL_BATCH_SIZE = 64 * 2

with strategy.scope():
    train_datasets = mnist_dataset(GLOBAL_BATCH_SIZE).repeat()
    options = tf.data.Options()
    options.experimental_distribute.auto_shard_policy = 
                                   tf.data.experimental.AutoShardPolicy.DATA
     train_datasets = train_datasets.with_options(options)
     multi_worker_model = build_and_compile_cnn_model()
```

multi_worker_model.fit(x=train_datasets, epochs=60, steps_per_epoch=5)

I have tried every possible way to understand what exactly is the model creation is waiting for but could not see any debug messages that point to an error.

```
2024-02-29 18:40:50.973973: I tensorflow/tsl/distributed_runtime/coordination/coordination_service.cc:551] /job:chief/replica:0/task:0 has connected to coordination service. Incarnation: 3159664859833219271
2024-02-29 18:40:50.974876: I tensorflow/tsl/distributed_runtime/coordination/coordination_service_agent.cc:299] Coordination agent has successfully connected.
2024-02-29 18:41:11.283570: I tensorflow/tsl/distributed_runtime/coordination/coordination_service.cc:551] /job:worker/replica:0/task:0 has connected to coordination service. Incarnation: 5929262018787784772
INFO:tensorflow:Enabled multi-worker collective ops with available devices: ['/job:chief/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0']
Number of devices: 2
Inside the strategy scope
INFO:tensorflow:Using MirroredStrat`your text`egy with devices ('/job:chief/task:0/device:CPU:0',)
INFO:tensorflow:Check health not enabled.
INFO:tensorflow:MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy with cluster_spec = {'chief': ['x.x.x.x:5001'], 'worker': ['y.y.y.y:5000']}, task_type = 'chief', task_id = 0, num_workers = 2, local_devices = ('/job:chief/task:0/device:CPU:0',), communication = CommunicationImplementation.AUTO
Shape of the NumPy array: 60000
```

Stuck here on both chief and worker ->>>>>>>>>**Model Creation**

I spent almost 3 weeks trying to finish my work on it but to no avail.